# Update table in phpmyadmin using input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to make an online gateway for my college, where staff can nominate students for particular post or prizes.  I used php with css for front end and phpmyadmin for back end.  But once i give the input(regno) to nominate a student, it doesn't update in the table.  Can anyone help? This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>NOMINATE ENTRIES</title>
<meta author="" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
</head>
<body id="main_body" >
    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">
        <h1><a>Nominate Entries</a></h1>
        <form name="form5" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="test.php">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <center><h2>Students Database</h2></center>
            <p><center><font size='3'>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","staff","12345","mop");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `Nominated` = 0");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Register No</th>
<th>Department &nbsp </th>
<th>Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
<th>Class &nbsp </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['RegNo'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$regno = $_POST['regno'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$sql = "UPDATE `mop`.`student` SET `Nominated` = \'1\' WHERE `student`.`RegNo` = 1106103;";}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</center></font>
            </p>
        </div>  
        <b>Enter Register Number <font color='red'>*</font> </b> <input type="text" id="regno" name="regno"><br>
        <b>Enter Reason <font color='red'>*</font> </b> <input type="text" id="reason" name="reason"><br>
            <ul >
                    <center><li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="768845" />
                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></center>
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: show your form as well

Comment: Note that phpmyadmin isn't a database: MySQL is the database with tables and indexy things and whotnot, and phpmyadmin is just a client script that can be used with it: your PHP code accesses MySQL, not phpmyadmin

Comment: yes i use phpmyadmin to run mysql.

Comment: updated the question to my full form guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually send your query.

```
$result = $connection -> query($sql);

// Or, since it is only an update

$connection -> query($sql);
```

Where `$connection` is the connection to your DB

Comment: i have actually connected it.see my full code i have updated my question again.

Comment: @YeshwanthVShenoy, You did not executed your updated query as you did for select query.After assigning query in variable you should execute it by using mysql_query

Comment: i cant get u sir can u explain more??

Comment: After your query string is prepared (after $sql in this case), you must call the query function. You did this with your SELECT statement a few lines up.. This is the line of code where you explicitly tell the computer that you would like to "run" your query. Also, probably less important, but your table's column headers and table rows aren't matching up. Your outputting the Name for the Dept and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the whole file like this sir. thanks all for ur input wanted to share it for others:

here is my form.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>NOMINATE ENTRIES</title>
<meta author="" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
</head>
<body id="main_body" >
    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">
        <h1><a>Nominate Entries</a></h1>
        <form name="form" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="test.php">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <center><h2>Students Database</h2></center>
            <p><center><font size='3'>
            <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","staff","123456","mop");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Register No</th>
<th>Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
<th>Department &nbsp </th>
<th>Class &nbsp </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['RegNo'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</center></font>
            </p>
        </div>  
        <b>Enter Register Number <font color='red'>*</font> </b> <input type="text" name="regno"><p>
        <b>Enter Reason <font color='red'>*</font> </b> <input type="text" name="reason"><p>

                    <ul >
                    <center><li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="768845" />
                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></center>
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

it refers to the test.php file and here is that file too:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","staff","123456","mop");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql1="UPDATE student SET Reason = '$_POST[reason]' WHERE RegNo ='$_POST[regno]'";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  else
  {
   $sql2="INSERT INTO nominated select * from student where regno = '$_POST[regno]'";
   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    else
    {
    $sql3="DELETE from student where regno = ".intval($_POST["regno"]);
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql3))
   {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
  }
 }
header("location:form5_1.php");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```